# local storage on blackberry that is not accessible from file explorer

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I have some html file that are downloaded post app startup. I would use the browserfield to display these html pages.

The assistance i need is to know;
Is there an internal writable directory where i can store my html files and access from browserfield, at the same time it should not be accessible from file explorer.
How do i read files from here using fileconnection
What should i write in browserField.requestContent("????????");

The html files need to be not accesible as they have certain logic which i would not like to expose to the end user.

Many Thanks in advance,
Godwin

Answer (score 1):

Question has been answered on the BB forum here:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/local-storage-writable-that-is-not-accessible-from-file-explorer/td-p/2806751

In summary, the answer given (and accepted) was that the downloaded files needed to be stored on the local file system (SD Card, internal storage).  Securing these files could be done with encryption.